# how can we rename _id field returned from groupby query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two schemas **users** and **lessons**. I have to fetch lessons group by each user. Also I am storing reference id of **user** in **lesson** schema.

To get the result I have done aggregate query in following format

```
db.lessons.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "user",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user"
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "user": "$user.email",
    "title": "$title",
    "scheduled_at": "$scheduled_at"
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$user",
    num_lessons: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    lessons: {
      $push: {
        title: "$title",
        schedule: "$scheduled_at"
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

From the above query I am able to get the output as below,

```
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "harry.quill@gmail.com"
    ],
    "num_lessons" : 1.0,
    "lessons" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "welcome to Mongoose",
            "schedule" : {
                "endTime" : ISODate("2017-06-12T08:30:00.000Z"),
                "startTime" : ISODate("2017-06-10T04:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : [ 
        "tom.quill@gmail.com"
    ],
    "num_lessons" : 1.0,
    "lessons" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "welcome to Angularjs",
            "schedule" : {
                "endTime" : ISODate("2017-05-31T09:30:00.000Z"),
                "startTime" : ISODate("2017-05-21T04:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to rename **_id** to **user**. Is it possible to achieve this in **aggregation** pipeline?

Comment: [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or better still [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in modern releases

Comment: @NeilLunn I have tried $project after `$group`, that is not working. Can you help me to understand how `$addFields` will work here.

Comment: `{ "$project": { "_id": 0, "user": "$_id", "num_lessons": 1, "lessons": 1 }` as your last stage, in addition to everything you have. Really though you should not do this. Your code should simply be accepting that the "primary key" is called `_id`. Adding another stage to aggregation means another pass through the data and it costs in time.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn . I was trying to keep `$project` in the last stage by removing first `$project`, hence i was not able to get the result. 
If adding other stage will add costs in time then do we have any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: @zulekha, please, measure before optimizing.

Answer (score 5):

we can do it by `$project`

```
db.lessons.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "user",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user"
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "user": "$user.email",
    "title": "$title",
    "scheduled_at": "$scheduled_at"
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$user",
    num_lessons: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    lessons: {
      $push: {
        title: "$title",
        schedule: "$scheduled_at"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    user: "$_id",
    num_lessons: '$num_lessons',
    lessons: '$lessons',
  }
}
])
```

I know, i am posting answer too late, but if anybody come here in future, it may helpful to them.